# Regex how to get parameter from url string. Jascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Hello I have a URL string:

```
'http://www.hello.com/index.php?page=11'
```

What is the regular expression that I have to execute to get the page number?

Comment: you can do it without any regexp `'http://www.hello.com/index.php?page=11'.split('page=')[1]`

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+)[^\d]*$
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/10

Comment: what if there are other arguments after page ?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It picks everything up.

Comment: This doesn't work, as well, if arguments after page contain digits.

Answer (score 0):

Use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to capture one or more digits which are present just after to `?page=`.

```
> var s = 'http://www.hello.com/index.php?page=11'
undefined
> var re = /\?page=(\d+)/;
undefined
> console.log(re.exec(s)[1])
11
> var re = /\bpage=(\d+)/;
undefined
> console.log(re.exec(s)[1])
11
```